# How to sort a set of pairs?

Tags: c++, sorting, set, qsort, std-pair

How shall I use the qsort function to sort a set of pairs ?
This is my set :

```
set< pair< int, int> > my_set
```

This I guess should be my compare function:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

Should my qsort look like this?

```
qsort (my_set, no_of_pairs, sizeof(int), compare);
```

When I sort them I want to sort by the values of a bi-dimensional array `**M;`, where

```
 M[my_set.first][my_set.second] = the_value
```

Comment: Can you explain your "P.S." - what do you want to sort according to? And please provide more code, than I can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Is this C++, or some other language?  Please include the primary language in the tags; it will get your question to the right people quicker.

Comment: Do not use `qsort` with std c++ containers. It's low level, error prone, it's interface is poor and rusty, and it performs worse in most cases.

Comment: Further, if you're using C++ (I've changed the tag for you since I'm moderately confident), you should not be using `qsort` but the `sort` algorithm. You probably want a comparator for pairs, too; how do you want to sort two pairs of int? By first value, and second value if the first are the same? Oh, no: probably you want to access an array with the indexes from the pairs.  Are you sure you want to sort the set of pairs rather than the array? That's all rather different from what you wrote, but then what you've written as a comparator is C-ish and not C++-ish.

Answer (score 1):

First, prefer std::sort to qsort with c++ std containers.
Secondly, you cannot sort a std::set a posteriori. `std::set` is sorted.
You can however specify a custom sorting for the std::set at instanciation using a 2nd template parameter.
Refer to the specs.

What you could do, if you need to sort the data after the fact, is use a std::vector instead. There is an algorithm that will cull the duplicate value.

This proposed solution assumes M is some global variable.

```
#include <algorithm>

bool less_than(const std::pair<int, int> &some, const std::pair<int, int> &other) {
    return M[some.first][some.second] < M[other.first][other.second]; 
}

std::sort(yourvector.begin(), yourvector.end(), less_than);
```

If M isn't a global variable, you could do something like that :

```
struc Compair { // see what I did there ? #sofunny
    bool operator() (const std::pair<int, int> &some, const std::pair<int, int> &other) {
        return M[some.first][some.second] < M[other.first][other.second]; 
    }
    int **M;
}
```

then in main :

```
Compair mycomparefunctor;
mycomparefunctor.M = arr; // arr is the original int **
std::sort(yourvector.begin(), yourvector.end(), mycomparefunctor);
```

EDIT :

If you must use a `std::set` then you should define the custom ordering when you declare it, like so :

```
Compair mypredicate;
mypredicate.M = arr; // arr is the original int **

std::set<std::pair<int, int>, mypredicate> myset;
// add stuff to the set. They will be sorted following your predicate.
```

Be careful though : in a set you cannot add 2 items that compare equal. So if your int ** 2D array has several values that are equal, you won't be able to have several pairs corresponding to indexes of equal value in the set.

Comment: This assumes that `yourset` in your example code isn't actually a `std::set` since `std::sort` requires random access iterators which `std::set` doesn't provide.

Comment: Yes. My bad, this is terrible. You cannot re-sort std::set. He could however use this as a predicate for the 2nd template argument of set. (which specifies a custom sorting IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this fairly wrong.

Let's assume that we know the maximum value for each member of the pair. If you don't know this, then you need to figure it out. I'm going to assume that it is `100`.

Then all we need to do is iterate over the set, and insert them into the new array. There's no faster way to go about this.

```
int M[100][100] = {};
for (auto const & pair : my_set)
    M[pair.first][pair.second] = the_value;
```

Comment: I strongly suspect you're solving a problem that isn't what the OP wants to solve.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I wouldn't be surprised.